# determining differences between generic lists

Tags: c#, mysql, performance, linq, collections

There are probably 10 duplicates of this question but I would like to know if there is a better way than I am currently doing this. This is a small example that I'm using to show how I'm determining differences:

```
        //let t1 be a representation of the ID's in the database.
        List<int> t1 = new List<int>() { 5, 6, 7, 8 };
        //let t2 be the list of ID's that are in memory.
        //these changes need to be reflected to the database.
        List<int> t2 = new List<int>() { 6, 8, 9, 10 };

        var hash = new HashSet<int>(t1);
        var hash2 = new HashSet<int>(t2);
        //determines which ID's need to be removed from the database
        hash.ExceptWith(t2); 
        //determines which ID's need to be added to the database.
        hash2.ExceptWith(t1);

        //remove contents of hash from database
        //add contents of hash2 to database
```

I want to know if I can determine what to add and remove in ONE operation instead of the two that I currently have to do. Is there any way to increase the performance of this operation? Keep in mind in the actual database situation there are hundreds of thousands of ID's.

**EDIT** or second question, is there a LINQ query that I can do directly on the database so I can just supply the new list of ID's and have it automatically remove/add itself? (using mysql)

**CLARIFICATION** I know I need two SQL queries (or a stored procedure). The question is if I can determine the differences in the list in one action, and if it can be done faster than this.

**EDIT2**

This operation from SPFiredrake appears to be faster than my hashset version - however I have no idea how to determine which to add and which to remove from the database. Is there a way to include that information in the operation?

```
t1.Union(t2).Except(t1.Intersect(t2))
```

**EDIT3**

Nevermind, I forgot that this statement in-fact has the problem of delayed execution, although in-case anyone is wondering, I solved my prior problem with it by using a custom comparer and an added variable determining which list it was from.

Comment: Post up your solution and mark it as accepted, you might just help someone out having the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, you're going to use a full outer join (which in LINQ world, is two GroupJoins). However, we ONLY care about values that don't have a matching record in either table. Null right value (left outer join) indicates a removal, null left value (right outer join) indicates an addition. So to get it to work this way, we just perform two left outer joins (switching the input for the second case to emulate the right outer join), concat them together (can use union, but unnecessary since we'll be getting rid of any duplicates anyway).

```
List<int> t1 = new List<int>() { 5, 6, 7, 8 };
List<int> t2 = new List<int>() { 6, 8, 9, 10 };

var operations = 
    t1.GroupJoin(
        t2, 
        t1i => t1i, 
        t2i => t2i, 
        (t1i, t2join) => new { Id = t1i, Action = !t2join.Any() ? "Remove" : null })
    .Concat(
        t2.GroupJoin(
            t1, 
            t2i => t2i, 
            t1i => t1i, 
            (t2i, t1join) => new { Id = t2i, Action = !t1join.Any() ? "Insert" : null })
    .Where(tr => tr.Action != null)
```

This will give you the select statement. Then, you can feed this data into a stored procedure that removes values that already exist in the table and add the rest (or two lists to run removals and additions against). Either way, still not the cleanest way to do it, but at least this gets you thinking.

Edit: My original solution was to separate out the two lists based on what action was needed, which is why it's so ghastly. The same can be done using a one-liner (not caring about which action to take, however), although I think you'll still suffer from the same issues (using LINQ [enumeration] as opposed to Hashsets [hash collection]).

```
// XOR of sets = (A | B) - (A & B), - being set difference (Except)
t1.Union(t2).Except(t1.Intersect(t2))
```

I'm sure it'll still be slower than using the Hashsets, but give it a shot anyway.

Edit: Yes, it is faster, because it doesn't actually do anything with the collection until you enumerate over it (either in a foreach or by getting it into a concrete data type [IE: List<>, Array, etc]). It's still going to take extra time to sort out which ones to add/remove and that's ultimately the problem. I was able to get comparable speed by breaking down the two queries, but getting it into the in-memory world (via ToList()) made it slower than the hashset version:

```
t1.Except(t2); // .ToList() slows these down
t2.Except(t1);
```

Honestly, I would handle it on the SQL side. In the stored proc, store all the values in a table variable with another column indicating addition or removal (based on whether the value already exists in the table). Then you can just do a bulk deletion/insertion by joining back to this table variable.

Edit: Thought I'd expand on what I meant by sending the full list to the database and have it handled in the sproc:

```
var toModify = t1.Union(t2).Except(t1.Intersect(t2));
mods = string.Join(",", toModify.ToArray());
// Pass mods (comma separated list) to your sproc.
```

Then, in the stored procedure, you would do this:

```
-- @delimitedIDs some unbounded text type, in case you have a LOT of records
-- I use XQuery to build the table (found it's faster than some other methods)
DECLARE @idTable TABLE (ID int, AddRecord bit)
DECLARE @xmlString XML
SET @xmlString = CAST('<NODES><NODE>' + REPLACE(@delimitedIDs, ',', '</NODE><NODE>') + '</NODE></NODES>' as XML)

INSERT INTO @idTable (ID)
SELECT node.value('.','int') 
FROM @xmlString.nodes('//NODE') as xs(node)

UPDATE id
SET AddRecord = CASE WHEN someTable.ID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM @idTable id LEFT OUTER JOIN [SomeTable] someTable on someTable.ID = id.ID

DELETE a
FROM [SomeTable] a JOIN @idTable b ON b.ID = a.ID AND b.AddRecord = 0

INSERT INTO [SomeTable] (ID)
SELECT id FROM @idTable WHERE AddRecord = 1
```

Admittedly, this just inserts some ID, it doesn't actually add any other information. However, you can still pass in XML data to the sproc and use XQuery in a similar fashion to get the information you'd need to add.

Comment: My version is actually 4 times faster than this on my system. (approximately) 1911ms for mine vs 7080ms for yours. I specificity mentioned performance as a concern.

Comment: You wanted a LINQ solution, I gave you one. My last sentence explained my thoughts on it. Eiher way, this is more a LINQ2SQL solution to generate a query, not deal with already persisted objects. Honestly, I think your method is probably going to be fastest (especially using hashsets).

Comment: Please see my update in the question. Your last statement there is quite fast.

Comment: I forgot that this was subject to delayed execution.

Answer (score 0):

even if you replace it with a Linq version you still need two operations.

let's assume you are doing this using pure SQL.

you would probably need two queries:

- one for removing the records
- another one for adding them

Using LINQ code it would be much more complicated and less readable than your solution

Comment: I know I need two SQL queries (or a stored procedure). The question is if I can determine the differences in the list in one action.

Comment: if for one action you mean one line of code yes you can do but you will probably concatenate 2 actions